# How to make the line like this?

Tags: html, css

How can I make a line like below, thank you

[image]

Comment: Please accept one of the answers if it answers your question. And also do up-vote good answers.

Answer (score 2):

I always use this code to make ‍‍‍steps. I hope it helps you

```
<div class="box">
   <div class="item" >  A  </div>

   <div class="line"></div>

   <div class="item" >  B  </div>

   <div class="line"></div>

   <div class="item" >  C  </div>
</div>
```

```
.box {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.line {
  width: 50px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use hr/
tag it means horizontal line you can adjust the width and height or make is stylish using css